# How to get first string of NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

Pretty straightforward question:

I have an array like so:

```
@[@"John Doe", @"Mister Appleseed", @"Steve"];
```

if it has two (or more) words, I want to delete them all but the first, so the output array should looke something like this:

```
@[@"John", @"Mister", @"Steve"];
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray * arr = @[@"John Doe", @"Mister Appleseed", @"Steve"];

NSMutableArray * tmp = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSString * s in arr)
{
    NSArray * cmpnts = [s componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    [tmp addObject:cmpnts[0]];
}

arr = tmp;
```

Answer (score 0):

You iterate over the array of names, split each at spaces (`" "`), and then grab the first object: the first name.

```
NSArray *nameArray = @[@"Name", @"Name Two"]; // original array
NSMutable *modifiedNameArray = [NSMutableArray new]; // new mutable array to add new names
for (NSString *fullName in nameArray) { // for loop
    NSString *firstName = [[fullName componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0]; // extract first name

    [modifiedNameArray addObject:firstName]; // add first name to mutable array
}
```

You have to have two arrays, because you cannot mutate an array while it is being used in a loop (even if it's an `NSMutableArray`).

Answer (score 0):

Check the following code:

```
    NSMutableArray *finalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSArray *sourceArray = @[@"John Doe", @"Mister Appleseed", @"Steve"];

    for(NSString *str in sourceArray){
          [finalArray addObject:[str componentsSepratedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0]];
    }
```